# Python code behaving differently between IDLE and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I'm completely new to programming, so I decided to teach myself python. While going through [the Non-Programmer's Tutorial for Python 3](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3), I stumbled across a strange occurrence. When I run this code:

```
def print_options():
    print('Options:')
    print(" 'p' print options")
    print(" 'c' convert from Celsius")
    print(" 'f' convert from Fahrenheit")
    print(" 'q' quit")

def c_to_f(c_temp):
    return 9.0/5.0 * c_temp + 32

def f_to_c(f_temp):
    return (f_temp-32)*5.0/9.0

choice = 'p'

while choice != 'q':
    if choice == 'c':
        temp = float(input('Celsius temp: '))
        print('Fahrenheit:', c_to_f(temp))
    elif choice == 'f':
        temp = float(input('Fahrenheit temp:'))
        print('Celsius:', f_to_c(temp))
    elif choice == 'p':
        print_options()
    choice = input('Options: ')
```

The resulting output is what you'd expect:

```
Options:
 'p' print options
 'c' convert from Celsius
 'f' convert from Fahrenheit
 'q' quit
Options: f
Fahrenheit temp:98.6
Celsius: 37.0
Options: c
Celsius temp: 37
Fahrenheit: 98.60000000000001
Options: q
```

But when I run the same code on Eclipse (IDLE was crashing so I tried something else), the program just loops instead of going into the other options:

```
Options:
 'p' print options
 'c' convert from Celsius
 'f' convert from Fahrenheit
 'q' quit
Options: c
Options:
 'p' print options
 'c' convert from Celsius
 'f' convert from Fahrenheit
 'q' quit
Options: f
Options:
 'p' print options
 'c' convert from Celsius
 'f' convert from Fahrenheit
 'q' quit
Options: q
Options:
 'p' print options
 'c' convert from Celsius
 'f' convert from Fahrenheit
 'q' quit
Options:
```

Is there something wrong in the code itself to cause this or is it just some wonky interaction? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The program looks ok in my opinion. Perhaps there is a bug with how Eclipse handle input. Are you using the latest version of PyDev? I suggest you try another IDE (like PyCharm).

Answer (score 0):

I`ve tried to run your code in IDLE and all is ok, in eclipse too. Try to reinstall last version of PyDev

Answer (score 0):

If the latest Eclipse/Pydev doesn't fix the issue, I'd recommend that you add a couple of debug/display lines to show you what Eclipse thinks it received as input.

Between these two lines:

```
while choice != 'q':
    if choice == 'c':
```

Add the following, indented at the same level as the if choice == 'c': line:

```
print ('debug1\tchoice =', choice)                # what you typed
print ('debug2\tlen(choice)=', len(choice))       # should be length of 1,
print ('debug3\tsame?', choice == choice.strip()) # should be True
```

If debug2 is not 1 or debug3 is not True, there's a sneaky gotcha with whitespace which could probably be resolved with changing this:

```
while choice != 'q':
```

to this:

```
while choice.strip() != 'q':
```

Also, I am curious about the description.  You said the code works ---  where did it work?  You said IDLE crashed and Eclipse does not work.

If you're using another editor (like Notepad++, PyScripter) or a different IDE (like PyCharm or WingIDE), do a Show Whitespace for the example code in both tools and verify that the code is indeed identical to what Eclipse/PyDev is running.

In Python, whitepsace (tabs, spaces) definitely matters and some tools interpret them slightly different --- especially in cases where you bounce back and forth between them.

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

try running the code through your terminal-- `$ python3 filename.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you run python in your terminal you will find it to be more accurate. In fact, I use eclipse and run everything in python launcher.